# ActivatedRoute is not an NgModule

Tags: angular

How do I include `ActivatedRoute` to my `ngModule` in Angular 2?

When I tried including `ActivatedRoute` in the `ngModule` I get error:

> ActivatedRoute is not an NgModule.

Comment: Why would you want to put `ActivatedRoute` in the module? :)

Comment: `ActivatedRoute` is Class(Provider) name which provides current route information, you shouldn't be including that in `imports` array..

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: i want to take id from url .  in angular1 i use $stateparams for  take id from url but when i search similar activity in angular2 i get  this      constructor( private _route:ActivatedRoute) { 
    console.log(this._route.snapshot.params['id']);
  }

Comment: @karthikavnair Well, it doesn't belong in the module. You import it to the component you need and inject it in your constructor :)

Comment: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-view',
  templateUrl: './view.component.html'
 
})
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {
  params;

  constructor( private _route:ActivatedRoute) { 
    console.log(this._route.snapshot.params['id']);
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  
}

Comment: @ Pankaj Parker thankyou  fro your answer

Comment: Made more clear as to where OP wants to add the ActivatedRoute

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding `ActivatedRoute`, you should set up Router correctly in your AppModule, e.g.:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule, 
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then `ActivatedRoute` will be available for injection in your components.